# Fetching large webhook in an optimal way

Tags: laravel, mongodb, rabbitmq, sendgrid

So I was sending a webhook from SendGrid, comprising 10000 records in it. At my endpoint, I am using rabbitmq queue to process the webhook further. The issue I am facing is in MongoDb update process as it is experiencing too much load. I've searched around and didn't get any results for this issue. What I was thinking to do is to send data to mongodb in chunks after consuming the message or is there any way around where I can receive the webhook in chunks before pushing it to my queue?